# How to check which control is clicked with one click event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, events, click, handler

What I'm trying to do is find out which control is clicked in my application without call `MouseClick` handler multi times for every control.
Assume that we have a form which contains some controls and then one of them is clicked by user and a Messagebox pups up and shows which control is clicked.
In other word there is just one handler with a sender argument so that sender tell me which control is clicked.
Something like below code:

```
private void MouseClicked(object sender, EventHandler e)
    {
        if(sender is Button)
        {
            //do something 
        }
        if (sender is Label)
        {
            //do something else
        }
        /*
         * .
         * .
         * .
         * 
        */
    }
```

Comment: Note that the `visual-studio` tag is intended for questions relating to the Visual Studio application, and not code you write with it.

Comment: What UI library are you using? Can you also clarify what your question is? It seems like you already understand how `sender` works.

Comment: Thanks for your respond and sorry because of that tag.
I use default UI library of the visual-studio (Windows Form).

Comment: Yes I know how click event is working but I need one event for multi control with different type.

Comment: Now that you've edited your question I've deleted my answer since it's clearly not the answer to the question as it is now. The code you've posted is valid and will do what you describe in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply select all the controls from the designer of the form and go to the events tab.

Double click on the mouse click event and one handler would be generated  for those events.